# Download a zip file

Tags: rust

I am trying to download a zip file from the Australian Bureau of Statistics with Rust.

The following python code works fine.

```py
import requests

def example():
    url = (
        "http://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/"
        "monthly-consumer-price-index-indicator/dec-2023/All-Time-Series-Spreadsheets.zip"
    ) 
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True, timeout=20)  
    if response.status_code == 200 and response.headers is not None:
        size = sum(len(chunk) for chunk in response.iter_content(8196))
        print(size)

example()  # prints 127525 (bytes)
```

However, when I try something similar in Rust (and I have tried a few different crates), I cannot get it to work. Example code following.

```rust
fn example() {
    let url = concat!(
        "http://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/",
        "monthly-consumer-price-index-indicator/dec-2023/All-Time-Series-Spreadsheets.zip"
    );
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let zip_bytes = client
        .get(url)
        .send().unwrap()
        .bytes().unwrap();
    println!("Length: {}", zip_bytes.len());
}

example()  // prints 70
```

Comment: Did you check the status code? (Try [`error_for_status()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html#method.error_for_status)).

Comment: The zip link also works via `https`, you may want to minimize your attack surface and drop `http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you are downloading from seems to reject (403) requests without a `User-Agent` HTTP header.

You can ask `reqwest` to include a user agent like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let url = concat!(
        "http://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/",
        "monthly-consumer-price-index-indicator/dec-2023/All-Time-Series-Spreadsheets.zip"
    );
    let client = reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder::new()
        .user_agent("reqwest")
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let zip_bytes = client
        .get(url)
        .send().unwrap()
        .bytes().unwrap();
    println!("Length: {}", zip_bytes.len());
}
```